# VS2019 - Cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to

Tags: c++

I'm using Amy Lib (https://github.com/liancheng/amy), but I have a issue, in which i dont have idea how to solve..

My error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2664   'std::basic_istringstream<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>::basic_istringstream(std::basic_istringstream<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>
> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to
> 'std::basic_istringstream<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>
> &&'   NM_Engine   ..\value_cast.hpp   96

```
template<>
inline sql_datetime value_cast(const char* s, unsigned long l) {
using namespace boost::posix_time;

std::istringstream in({s, l}); // error in this line
in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(),
                     new time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%F")));

sql_datetime v;
in >> v;
return v;
}
```

Thank you so much guys

Comment: Does the error go away if you explicitly construct a string with `std::string{s, l}` ?

Comment: What is `in({s, l})` supposed to do? This is trying to pass an initializer list to an `istringstream` constructor

Comment: @jkb, thanks for answer, the error is in this line:
https://github.com/liancheng/amy/blob/master/include/amy/detail/value_cast.hpp#L96

My project have this lib, but with vs2019 I have this issue.

Comment: @Botje, thank you for answer, I have tryed, but problem still.

Comment: @SimidaGG, that's the line I'm asking you about. As @Botje seems to be suggesting, try `std::istringstream in(std::string{s, l})